# How to emit event to another component that is not a parent in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

So the first component in the example below simply just imports other components and then renders them in the template.  Among the components being imported, I have a Stages component and a StageExecutionTimes component.  What I'm trying to do is when a user clicks on an icon in the Stage component, I want to then hide the StageExecutionTimes component.  My understanding is that I will need to use `$emit` from the Stages component to send the event to the parent which will then hide the StageExecutionsComponent.  I am trying to set `showgraph` as a boolean which is then used as a prop between the components.  I am then trying to change the value of `showgraph` via `$emit`.

The code below does not seems to be affecting or changing the value of `showgraph` in the main component

## main component that imports and renders subcomponents

```
<template>
  <div id="vue-main">
    <NavBar></NavBar>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div :v-bind="showgraph"><StageExecutionTimes></StageExecutionTimes></div>
    </transition>
    <transition name="fade">
      <Stages></Stages>
    </transition>
    <transition name="fade">
      <Overview></Overview>
    </transition>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar.vue";
import Stages from "../components/execution_details/Stages.vue";
import Binaries from "../components/execution_details/Binaries.vue";
import StageExecutionTimes from "../components/graphs/StageExecutionTimes.vue";
import Overview from "../components/execution_details/Overview.vue";

export default {
  name: "execution_details",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      showgraph: true
    };
  },
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Stages,
    StageExecutionTimes,
    Overview,
  },
```

## ../components/execution_details/Stages.vue";

```
  <template>
  <div class="stages">
    <template v-if="job_execs.length > 0">
    <h3>Stages</h3>
    <a href="#" @click="!showgraph"><img src="@/assets/charticon.png"></a>
    <transition name="fade" appear mode="out-in">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <template v-for="item in job_execs">
          <tr>
            <td
              v-for="stage_execution in item.stage_execution"
              :class="stage_execution.status.name"
              :title="stage_execution.exec_node.name"
              :key="stage_execution.stage.name"
            >
              <br />
              {{ stage_execution.duration | durationReadable }}
              <br />
              {{ stage_execution.status.name }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </transition>
  </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { calculateDuration } from "../../helpers/time.js";
import { liveDuration } from "../../helpers/time.js";
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  name: "Stages",
  props: ["showgraph"],
  data() {
    return {
      job_execs: []
    };
  },
```

How can I hide StageExecutionTimes component when charticon is clicked in the Stages component?

Also, can I accomplish this WITHOUT even touching StageExecutionTimes component?  It seems like I could just pass the event from Stages to the main component and then from there just hide StageExecutionTimes.

Comment: You'll have to either manually propagate the events all the way up and down or create an event bus.

Comment: Took 5 seconds to google it: https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Answer (score 0):

if you have many components to share datas,you need a vuex store.
you click the  then you change the datas in the store, and in your  you use v-if="isShow"

```
@click="hideOtherComponent"

hideOtherComponent(){
     this.store.commit('HIDE_COMPONENT');
}

computed: {
    isShow() {
    return store.state.StageExecutionTimesShow
    }
}

<component v-if="isSHow">
```

` 
[vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/zh/guide/state.html)

Comment: I am currently not using vuex

Answer (score 0):

Have the components a common high level parent? If the answer is yes, you can $emit the change to the parent, and pass to the other child the data trought a Prop.